# ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib64/pgsql/hstore.so": /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I’m trying to enable hstore on my PostgreSQL database running on an Amazon Linux AMI. I’ve already jumped through a ton of hurdles and ended up with this error that I can’t get past:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib64/pgsql/hstore.so": /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/pgsql/hstore.so)
```

I run `ldd --version` to get my version of GLIBC and it returns `ldd (GNU libc) 2.17`.

The only solutions that I've come across suggest

1. Running `yum update`, which doesn’t make much sense because my system appears to be running a more recent version than that required.
2. Recompiling the program against the version of `glibc` that’s on your system, which I don’t quite understand. What program would I have to recompile? PostgreSQL?

This has been driving me nuts for days and I have run into a corner. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes; You should be recompiling postgres

Comment: Is there any other solution? This is a huge production db machine for a service that needs to be up 24/7

Comment: Have you tried creating a snapshot, and doing the first solution, because if its a dll problem you will experience downtime.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) shared library, so it is probably the only one that needs compiling with your version of GLIBC. The one contained in your postgres package evidently was compiled with version 2.14, while yours is 2.17.

Normally `hstore` should be satisfied with a higher-level version, but the check it does is apparently “equal-to 2.14” instead of “greater-or-equal-to 2.14.”

The article [PostgreSQL feature highlight: `hstore`](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-feature-highlight-hstore/) describes how to
install the `hstore` library from the source code:

> After downloading the source code and installing the core, do the
>   following commands.
>
> ```
> cd $PG_SOURCE_ROOT
> cd contrib/hstore
> make install
> ```
>
> At this point all the libraries and files related to hstore are
>   installed in $INSTALL_FOLDER/share/extension.
>
> ```
> $ ls $INSTALL_FOLDER/share/extension
> hstore--1.0--1.1.sql  hstore--1.1.sql  hstore--unpackaged--1.0.sql  hstore.control
> ```
>
> Then connect to your Postgres server and finish hstore installation
>   with CREATE EXTENSION command.
>
> ```
> postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
> CREATE EXTENSION
> postgres=# \dx hstore
>                          List of installed extensions
>    Name  | Version | Schema |                   Description                    
> --------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------
>  hstore | 1.1     | public | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
> (1 row)
> ```
>
> With a psql client, '\dx' allows to check the list of extensions
>   already installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on Manjaro Linux (a fork of Arch), and I had this after I had upgraded Postgres from version 10 to 11.

(The path was slightly different for me. I got: `could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/hstore.so"`.)

I followed the [arch wiki instructions on upgrading postgres](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL), and was up and running in no time.

Answer (score -1):

Get a newer hstore.so yours is to old for the system you're running. Or try to find a compat-glibc package for glueing.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. I haven't been able to find any standalone copies of hstore.so on the web. I suspect that I may be going about it the wrong way -- how would you suggest updating only the hstore.so file?